# Recursive binary search function for Intel x86 ASM

Tags: assembly, x86

I have been tasked to write a recursive binary search function in intel x86 asm on ia-32 according to the following C code

```
int binary_search(int n, int list[], int low, int high) 
{

int middle;

if (low > high) {
    return -1;
}
       
middle = low + (high-low) / 2;

if (n == list[middle]) {
    return middle;
}
if (n < list[middle]) {
    high = middle - 1;
} else {
    low = middle + 1;
}
    
return binary_search(n, list, low, high);
}
```

This is my assembly code. It gives a seg fault unless the the parameters passed in are (n=11,list={10,11},low=0,high=2) which results in 1 and (n=5,list={3,5,7},low=0,high=3) which also results in 1. Could anyone point out what the problem is please? I am new assembly and ia-32.

```
;*****************************************************************************
;* int binary_search(int n, int list[], int low, int high);                  *
;*****************************************************************************
%define high [ebp+20]
%define low [ebp+16]
%define list [ebp+12]
%define n [ebp+8] ;;;define variables
binary_search:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp ; initialise stack frame

  mov eax, low 
  cmp eax, high  

  jg .baseCase ; if low > high, .baseCase
  jle .middle ; if low <= high, .middle

.baseCase:
  mov eax, -1
  pop ebp
  ret

.middle: ;calculate middle
  push ebx
  push ecx
  push edx
  push esi
  push edi

;middle = low + (high-low) / 2
  mov eax, high
  sub eax, low 
  sar eax, 1
  
  xor ecx, ecx ; clean ecx
  xor edx, edx ; clean edx

  mov esi, list
  mov ecx, n

  mov ebx, [esi+eax*4] ; ebx <- list[middle]
  mov edi, eax ; edi <- eax

  cmp ecx, ebx ; if list[middle] == n, return mid
  jl .recurseDecHigh
  jg .recurseIncLow

  pop edi
  pop esi
  pop edx
  pop ecx
  pop ebx
  pop ebp
  ret ; return middle, currently in eax

.recurseDecHigh:
  mov eax, list
  push eax
  mov eax, n
  mov eax, low
  push eax
  mov eax, edi
  dec eax
  push eax

  xor ecx, ecx
  xor edx, edx

  call binary_search

  pop edi
  pop esi
  pop edx
  pop ecx
  pop ebx
  pop ebp
  ret

.recurseIncLow:
  mov eax, list
  push eax
  mov eax, n
  push eax
  mov eax, edi
  inc eax
  push eax
  mov eax, high
  push eax

  xor ecx, ecx
  mov edx, edx

  call binary_search

  pop edi
  pop esi
  pop edx
  pop ecx
  pop ebx
  pop ebp
  ret
```

`

Comment: Use your debugger, step through the code and figure out where the problem is. That would be my answer even if you were working with the C code rather than assembly.

Comment: You're doing `middle = (high - low) / 2`, which is not what the C code says.  Have you tried single stepping to see if the values in the assembly compare to the values in the C code at the same point in the algorithm?  Start by running the C code in the debugger to see what values you will be expecting for variables, then compare with the assembly run in debugger.

Comment: Also, check all the registers, including the stack pointer for improper movement or improper restoration.  When it seg faults, find out what instruction causes that, and determine how that instruction got a bad value.  Get to know your data (the array and the stack), so you know what good pointers and bad pointers look like.